# Website crashes on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, crash, scriptaculous

I recently designed a website, which is all fine. I am personally pleased with it, but when I tried to open it with Internet Explorer 8, it crashes, and show's the Don't Send window.
I am really stuck here. The link is : http://galant-jeans.x10.mx , and the pages giving problems are the gallery pages. http://galant-jeans.x10.mx/dyer_galeri.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by crash? The page loaded for me in IE9.

Comment: Your gallery page is not using jQuery - it uses scriptaculous/prototype.

Comment: Can you also try it in IE8 if it's not too much of a hassle ?
And also did  you check the door gallery I specified ?

Comment: It loads without problem on my side too. Using IE 8.0.7

Comment: Okay, thanks. So it might be my computer. And does the lightbox on the images work ?

Comment: Hey Jon, it works fine in my IE8.

Comment: No problems with IE 8.0 and FF. Maybe you are in quirksmode ?

Comment: I see, there are some styles missing on the navigation, gallery works tho

Comment: tip:  IE is sensitive to trailing comas in json objects and missing ;
try http://www.jslint.com/  that could help you find the problem

Comment: Allright, thanks for the input guys, I really appreciate it.
But now I have another question. Why doesn't the navigation bar style work on IExplorer ? I am kind of a starter here, so please help me.

Comment: Please ask a new question for this.